# Random walk in python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to implement a random walk in python. This is the error I get. I feel my implementation is wrong or at least not the best. Can someone have a look at it. Keep in mind I am a beginner in python and this is how I think someone would code something, so I can be totally off.

```
in randomWalk(stepSize, stepNumber)
     37     for _ in range(stepNumber):
     38         r = randint(1,4)
---> 39         x,y = movement[r]
     40         xList.append(x)
     41         yList.append(y)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

This is my code

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rnd
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})

x = 0.
y = 0.
xList = []
yList = []
def goRight(stepSize, y):
    direction = np.cos(0)
    x = stepSize*direction
    return [x,y]

def goUp(stepSize, x):
    direction = np.cos(90)
    y = stepSize*direction
    return [x,y]

def goLeft(stepSize, y):
    direction = np.cos(180)
    x = stepSize*direction
    return [x,y]

def goDown(stepSize, x):
    direction = np.cos(270)
    y = stepSize*direction
    return [x,y]

def randomWalk(stepSize, stepNumber):
    movement = {1: goRight, 
                2: goUp, 
                3: goLeft, 
                4: goDown}

    for _ in range(stepNumber):
        r = randint(1,4)
        x,y = movement[r]
        xList.append(x)
        yList.append(y)


    plt.ioff()
    plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


randomWalk(1.,4)
```

Comment: @LeeWhite I don't. Where should that go?

Comment: @das-g. You are absolutely right. Sorry!!!

Comment: You probably want the changed coordinate to still depend on it's previous value, e.g. `x = x + stepSize` instead of `x = stepSize * direction`. (As you seem to move on a Cartesian grid, I also don't think you need the directions you compute. Just add or subtract the stepSize from the appropriate coordinate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting functions in your dict `movement`. `movement[r]` is not calling the function, only accessing them. What you line is basically doing, is:

```
x, y = goDown
```

If you want to call the function in that line, you have to add parentheses and arguments, something like:

```
x, y = movement[r](stepSize, x)
```

Which shows that you have a problem in your design, since some functions expect `x` and some expect `y`. You could maybe fix that by having all the functions take both coordinates, x and y, and then your line should go like

```
x, y = movement[r](stepSize, x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line

```
x,y = movement[r]
```

The dictionary movement is a list of ints to functions when you call movement[r] only a single function is returned, but here you are trying to unpack it. Instead I think you want:

```
 x,y = movement[r](stepSize)
```

This will call your function and so return the coords you want.
Also you need to change all your step methods to only take the one parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a function in a dictionary of fucntions like this , use this instead :

```
functionToCall = movement[r] # look up for function in dictionary
x,y = functionToCall(stepsize , x, y) # then call function with desired parameters
```